# Regex remove entire line

Tags: regex, rust

I have a file that looks like:

```rs
mod one;
mod two;
mod three;

fn init() {}
```

Now I want to remove `mod two` using a simple Regex pattern, using the [regex crate](https://docs.rs/regex/1.4.3/regex/) like:

```rs
let mod_pattern = regex::Regex::new("mod two;");
let mod_match = mod_pattern.captures(&file_contents).expect("Unable to get matches for mod two");
let mod_match_location = mod_match.get(0).expect("Unable to get mod two match group");

file_contents.replace_range(mod_match_location.start()..mod_match_location.end(), "");
```

This works, but it leaves my file looking like:

```rs
mod one;

mod three;

fn init() {}
```

I'm wondering how I can get rid of the entire line instead of leaving an empty line in its place. I realized I could do:

```rs
file_contents.replace_range(mod_match_location.start()-5 ..mod_match_location.end(), "");
```

and then run rustfmt but this assumes that the end user of my library is using 4 space indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also match the following newline (and possible carriage return), so instead your pattern would look like `r"mod two;\r?\n?"`. The newline is optional, as otherwise it won't match if `"mod two;"` is the last line in the file.

If you also want to support e.g. `"  mod two;  "`, i.e. extra horizontal whitespace. Then you can use `[ \t]*` before and after, to optionally match zero-to-many spaces or tabs. To ensure that matching is done from the start of the line, you could use `^`, which requires enabling multi-line mode with `(?m)`. All in all, the final pattern could look like this:

```
r"(?m)^[ \t]*mod two;[ \t]*\r?\n?"
```

Note that you can't use `\s*` in place of `[ \t]*` as `\s` also matches newlines. Thereby if `mod two;` was surrounded by blank lines, then these would be trimmed too.

---

I'm assuming you're using regex, because you want to do some more complex matching and substitution later. However, if not then you could instead use [`lines()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines), [`filter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter), [`collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) and then [`join()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.join).

```rust
let file_contents = file_contents
    .lines()
    .filter(|&line| line.trim() != "mod two;")
    .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    .join("\n");
```